# Flutter: Then() block code is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I am fetching some data from an API and while fetching the data I am showing a loading spinner. Then after fetching the data I want to show my data on the screen but the problem is that the loading spinner never stop.
Also I have this error: E/flutter (10577): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import '../provider/weekDaysAndWorkTime.dart';
 import '../provider/daysAndTimes.dart';
 import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
 import './dailyListScreen.dart';

 class ChooseWtimeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _ChooseWtimeScreenState createState() => _ChooseWtimeScreenState();
 }

  //This page is for selecting the work time employee and the day of the week.

 class _ChooseWtimeScreenState extends State<ChooseWtimeScreen> {
 bool _isLoading = false;
 bool _isInit = true;

 @override
 void didChangeDependencies() {
 if (_isInit) {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });
  Provider.of<DaysAndTime>(context).fetchAndSet().then((_) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }
 _isInit = false;
 super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

In the above code, there is my then() block code which must stop the loading spinner and show the fetched data but the loading spinner never stops. I don't know what is the problem!

```
  String _selectedWorkTime;
  String _selectedWeekDay;

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List<WeakDays> days = Provider.of<DaysAndTime>(context).days;
List<EmpWorkTime> times = Provider.of<DaysAndTime>(context).times;

List<EmpWorkTime> workTime = times;

List<String> _workTimeItems = workTime.map((wt) => wt.persianName).toList();
var weekDays = days;
List<String> _weekDaysItems = weekDays.map((wd) => wd.persianName).toList();
return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
        child: Center(
            child: _isLoading
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : Container(
                    height: 600,
                    width: 400,
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("روز هفته: "),
                          SizedBox(width: 5),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 150,
                              child: DropdownButton(
                                  items: _weekDaysItems
                                      .map((weekDaysStringItem) =>
                                          DropdownMenuItem(
                                              value: weekDaysStringItem,
                                              child:
                                                  Text(weekDaysStringItem)))
                                      .toList(),
                                  onChanged: (newItem) {
                                    _selectedWeekDay = newItem;
                                  }))
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Row(children: [
                        Text("وقت کاری: "),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 150,
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              items: _workTimeItems
                                  .map((dropdownStringItem) =>
                                      DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: dropdownStringItem,
                                          child: Text(dropdownStringItem)))
                                  .toList(),
                              onChanged: (newItem) {
                                _selectedWorkTime = newItem;
                              }),
                        ),
                      ]),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text("تاًیید"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            EmpWorkTime empWorkTime = workTime.firstWhere(
                                (element) =>
                                    element.persianName ==
                                    _selectedWorkTime);
                            WeakDays weekDay = weekDays.firstWhere(
                                (element) =>
                                    element.persianName ==
                                    _selectedWeekDay);
                            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                DailyListScreen.routeName,
                                arguments: [
                                  weekDay.weekDayId,
                                  empWorkTime.employeeWorkTimeId
                                ]);
                            
                          }),
                    ]),
                  ))));
```

}
}

Comment: Did you check `fetchAndSet()` method is done by using `print` method? Try printing any code in `setState` in `then` block.

Comment: who is calling await on that Future?

Comment: Yes, the fetch and set method is working well and it is fetching the data and it prints as well. But about the then I didn't print any thing till now. ok I will try that.

Comment: Is there any one to help me please?